# If the text doesn't fit on the same row don't display all

Tags: javascript, css

I have a left sidebar on my website which contains a list with links. If one link is very long, it won't fit on only one row.
For example: 'This is a very long long long link'.
What can I do to display as much as posible from this text (eg. 'This is a very long') but in such a way that it will fit on only one row (one row has 200px width)?

Comment: Please listen to @Truth. We give our time to you for free, the least you can do is help the community by giving back a little.

Comment: Yes. I did this. I usually vote good answers as usefull, but I forgot to accept them.

Comment: If you can comment that you forget to accept answers – you could accept one too, right? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the CSS to:

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS3 property called `text-overflow` that controls just what you describe. In combination with `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;` you can customize what is displayed at the end of the line.

There's documentation [here](http://dochub.io/#css/text-overflow) that's good and describes the property's flexibility. But let's say all you want to do is add an ellipsis (…) to the end of lines that exceed their width, then all you have to write is :

```
.sidebar p { /*Or whatever selector matches*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow: hidden;` on the container, along with a set width and height.